# How do I map guest OS to separate interface?

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

I have two physical interfaces on host (Ubuntu 16.04) is it possible to bridge one VM network to first interface, and the other to the second in VMware Player 12?

I can add a Network adapter under Settings/Hardware but there's no option to bind it to any interface so in guest I get 2 network interfaces to the same host interface.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, VMware hides a lot of options for free Player options so you gotta do some digging.

First i ran VMware netconfig tool `sudo /usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-netcfg` by default you should have

> vmnet0 (Bridged to: Automatic)
>
> vmnet1 (host-only)
>
> vmnet8 (NAT)

i manually bridged vmnet0 to my first ethernet card so there's no magic, and created new network, vmnet2, and bridged it to the second ethernet card.

Then through the vmplayer GUI added a new Network Adapter: edit VM > (in Hardware tab) "+ Add ..." button > "Network Adapter"

Then got to manually edit the vmware config file to map second Network Adapter to vmnet2. To do that edit you vmx file (~vmware/VMNAME/VMNAME.vmx) and change/set these lines `ethernet1.connectionType = "custom"` and `ethernet1.vnet = "vmnet2"`
Ta da that should be all